# Serilog SQL Server logging only works with AuditTo not WriteTo

Tags: c#, sql-server, serilog, .net-7.0

I can't seem to find out what the problem is with Serilog. Please see the following setup which saves records to the sql database when set to AuditTo but when I change it to WriteTo, no records are saved at all.

This is in the Program.cs

```
public static int Main(string[] args) 
{                                  
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new
        ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    using var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
        .UseSerilog()            
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
              webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                                                             
         });
    }
```

My appsettings are..

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "AuditTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=tcp:????.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=?????;User ID=?????;Password=????;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=True;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "preserveStaticLogger": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This only seems to be an issues when called from a controller using the following static way...

```
Log.Information("Logging index model!");
```

I've also tried using the DI method. Both work fine when set to AuditTo just nothing when WriteTo.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check the server log files.  Using SQL Server Management Studio the log files will be in the explorer under Management.

Comment: I can't see the log files. Is this because it's an Azure SQL db?

Comment: It is a permission issue.  An Admin would need to look at log files or change permissions.  I think you need to change the roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-server-roles?force_isolation=true&view=azuresql

Comment: Does AuditTo have different permissions to WriteTo on the database?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16